# Is class instrumentation removed when profiling session ends?

Tags: java, jvm, jprofiler

When JProfiler instruments classes during a profiling session, are those classes left instrumented after the profiling session ends?
Or will JProfiler "uninstrument" the modified classes?

marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JProfiler will not uninstrument classes except when you change filter settings.

If this is a concern, use sampling instead of instrumentation.